# Instagram Api: Can I block and unblock the user who follows me?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have just covered the documentation of Instagram Api; but there is no block or unblock service that the api has support. However there are some apps that getting the list of users and i can get block a user following me. So how can i block a user whether from instagram api or not? If api does not really support blocking a user, so any other way to block the instagram user that follows me?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It was possible with old APIs, if you had signed up for Instagram API before Nov 17th 2015, you can do block/unblock

Go to http://gramfeed.com, login, lookup a user and you can block/unblock

Comment: Thanks krisrak for your answer. But i need to use just the blocking and unblocking feature however i can do? Is there anyway to block and unblock the user with another solution?(Html parse, ajax post request vs..)